# Uniformly convex, uniformly smooth Banach space which is not convex of power type

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

It is well known that every uniformly convex Banach space $X$ admits an equivalent norm which such that it is convex of power type, i.e. the modulus of convexity with respect to the new norm satisfies $\delta_X(\varepsilon)\geq C\varepsilon^p$ for some $p$ but the same need not be true for the original norm.

Is there an example of Banach space which is uniformly convex and uniformly smooth which is not convex of power type?

Comment: Isn't it enough to consider a norm on $\mathbb R^2$ whose unit ball (uniformly convex) has a contact of infinite order at $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$ with the square $\partial([-1,1]^2)$, such as $y(x)=1-e^{-1/x}$ on a neighborhood of $0$ ?

Comment: Erm, $y(x)=1-e^{-1/|x|}$, of course... Anything with vanishing derivatives of all orders at $0$ and strictly concave.